# How do I position a menu list underneath the drop down icon?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Whenever I click on the drop down menu (the 3 bars) it opens up a menu, but in the wrong place. I want it to open underneath the 3 bars, instead its opening up where the navigation usually is when the screen is bigger.

To check my code, considering its over 3 files and I dont know where the mistake even could be, or how to remedy it, Ill link the github repo.
https://github.com/Realmm/James-Website

You have to make the screen small to see the bars, where the problem occurs.

Big screen:

[image: big screen]

Small screen:

[image: small screen]

Open menu:

[image: open menu]

Comment: Could you put the code in a JSFiddle? It might be easier for folks to run it that way. (edit: or just in a code snippet in the question?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a W3 Schools example that seems similar to what you want: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown_navbar.asp

The key difference between the example and what you have so far seems to be that the example nests the dropdown navigation menu inside the button that opens the dropdown.

I tried nesting your mobile-menu element into the icon element, and that does make the menu appear below the bars icon when it opens. You might still want to fix some style details, but is that about the right idea?

```
<i class="fa fa-bars">
    <nav class="mobile-menu">
      <p class="nav-box contact">Contact</p>
      <p class="nav-box services">Services</p>
      <p class="nav-box portfolio">Portfolio</p>
      <p class="nav-box about">About</p>
    </nav>
  </i>
```

Edit: I also added `overflow: hidden;` to the bar icon's CSS, and that stopped it from stretching the header's height when it opens.

Since this fix also made the original nav links not appear on the right side of the header when the screen is expanded, I made one more edit to add a separate html element for each version of the nav links, and added a new $mobileNavBar variable in the JavaScript to track the opening and closing of the dropdown version. Basically, I added this line:

```
let $mobileNavBox = $('.fa-bars .nav-box');
```

And I changed this chunk:

```
on('click', () => {
  $navBox.slideToggle();
  $navBox.css('display', 'block');
  $navBox.css('position', '')
```

To this:

```
on('click', () => {
  $mobileNavBox.slideToggle();
  $mobileNavBox.css('display', 'block');
  $mobileNavBox.css('position', '')
```

Here is a working example:

```js
let $bar = $('.header .fa-bars');
let $navBox = $('.header .nav-box');
let $mobileNavBox = $('.fa-bars .nav-box');
let $window = $(window);

$bar.on('mouseenter', () => {
  $bar.css({
    cursor: 'pointer',
    color: '#368EC9'
  });
}).on('mouseleave', () => {
  $bar.css({
    color: '#FFF'
  });
}).on('click', () => {
  $mobileNavBox.slideToggle();
  $mobileNavBox.css('display', 'block');
  $mobileNavBox.css('position', '')
});

$navBox.on('mouseenter', event => {
  $(event.currentTarget).css({
    cursor: 'pointer',
    color: '#368EC9',
    backgroundColor: '#37393D'
  });
}).on('mouseleave', event => {
  $(event.currentTarget).css({
    color: '#FFF',
    backgroundColor: '#333'
  });
});

$window.resize(() => {
  if ($window.width() > 800) {
    $navBox.css('display', 'inline-block');
  } else {
    $navBox.css('display', 'none');
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
}

mobile-menu {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #414141;
  font-family: Montserrat, serif;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #FFF;
  height: 50px;
}

.grid .header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 30px minmax(400px) 400px 1fr 1fr;
  /* border: 1px solid #FFF; */
  grid-template-areas: 'title title empty empty nav';
}

.empty {
  grid-area: empty;
}

.header .title {
  grid-area: title;
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  /* border: 1px solid #FFF; */
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto 10px;
}

.header .nav-box {
  grid-area: nav;
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #333;

  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin: auto 5px;
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding: 12px 4px 0px 4px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 38px;
  /* border: 1px solid #FFF; */
}

.header .fa {
  grid-area: bar;
  font-size: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto 0px auto 10px;
  /* border: 1px solid #FFF; */
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .header .nav-box {
    display: none;
    float: none;
  }

  .header .fa {
    display: inline;
  }

  .grid .header {
    grid-template-areas: 'bar title title title title';
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>James Andrew</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="empty"></div>
      <i class="fa fa-bars">
        <nav class="mobile-menu">
          <p class="nav-box contact">Contact</p>
          <p class="nav-box services">Services</p>
          <p class="nav-box portfolio">Portfolio</p>
          <p class="nav-box about">About</p>
        </nav>
      </i>
      <p class="title">James Andrew</p>
      <nav class="mobile-menu">
        <p class="nav-box contact">Contact</p>
        <p class="nav-box services">Services</p>
        <p class="nav-box portfolio">Portfolio</p>
        <p class="nav-box about">About</p>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/menu.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Didnt fix the issue for me?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/auhkcpb2/
And if you resize the window, it doesnt show the original nav-box's

Comment: Hmm, I see what you mean. Maybe you can make the dropdown and the original nav-box two separate elements?

Comment: Edited the answer - did that fix it for you?

Comment: Yeah that worked, thank you! Just needed to update the $mobileNavBox color to white when you click the bar because it was playing up color wise, but everything else is great, thanks!